# Component of web-aware scopes are not created during app initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I'm using `springBootVersion = '2.5.4'` and trying to autowire the following component:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class TokenDecodingService {
   
   @Autowired
   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
/* Some logic with request */
}
```

into my controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
//@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
public class DrupalEnhancedController {

    @Autowired
    TokenDecodingService tokenDecodingService;

    ....

}
```

During debugging I see that I get `No Scope registered for scope name 'request'` exception. The same problem goes for each web-aware scope.

First, I thought that I was using the wrong application context, but I've figured out that I'm using `AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext` and this context should accept web-aware scopes of beans/components.

Also I tried to define this logic inside a bean like this:

```
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public TokenDecodingService tokenDecodingService() {
        return new TokenDecodingService();
    }
```

and tried to define context listener manually:

```
@Bean 
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

But unfortunatelly I didn't make any progress this way.
I think that the root cause here is the absence of web-aware contexts, so how can I enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned `AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext`, so I assume you have a reactive web application. There's no such thing as "request scope" or even `HttpServletRequest` in a reactive application, since in a general case such application is not servlet-based.

You might want to inject the reactive `ServerHttpRequest` into your controller method instead:

```java
@RestController
public class DrupalEnhancedController {

    @GetMapping("/someurl")
    public Mono<SomeResponse> get(ServerHttpRequest request) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, that was the case. It helped me to remove spring.main.web-application-type: reactive in my application yaml and use spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul rather than spring cloud gateway. Unfortunately it doesn't work out of the box with spring boot 2.5.2 version so I had to implement the workaround mentioned here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4008